# Компилирование Go программы с использованием, с, с++ компиляторов

Tags: c, golang

Как я могу понизить размер Golang программы использовав C++, C компиляторы для статической линковки.

OS: windows 8.1

main.go:

```
package main 

func main() {
    println("Hello");
}
```

Platform: AMD64:

```
С выключенным CGO размер - 998kb
С выключенным CGO, DWARF информацией и стрипом - 633kb

С включенным CGO размер - 998kb
С включенным CGO, DWARF информацией и стрипом - 633kb
```

Platform: 386:

```
С выключенным CGO размер - 880kb
С выключенным CGO, выключенной DWARF информацией и стрипом - 548kb

С включенным CGO размер - 880kb (одно и тоже)
С включенным CGO, выключенной DWARF информацией и стрипом - 548kb (одно и тоже)
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Если брать GCC компилятор для платформы AMD64 результат будет - 53kb. В чем дело? 
Устанавливая `CGO_ENABLED=0` я не получаю никакого результата, в чем дело?

Как мне уменьшить/сократить размер моего .exe файла до минимума скомпилировав со статической линковкой от другого компилятора? (без использования UPX и т.д)

Comment: Компиляторы си по умолчанию используют динамическую линковку. `gcc -static hello.c` даёт бинарь на 828K.

Comment: @Ainar-G у меня при `gcc -static main.c` выдает 53 кб

Comment: Проще сразу писать на С/С++, в Go в *.ехе добавляет свой CLR, он и добавляет вес.

Comment: @vnn198 если бы знал С, С++ давно бы на них только и писал :) То есть как я понял уйти от такого размера в Go не возможно?

Comment: Размер это плата за относительную простоту кода, если хочется прям минимальный размер то надо учить ASM, чем проще код для написания программ тем дороже это стоит в занимаемом объёме, например Node.JS заметно проще Go, но за это платишь размерами приложений и занимаемой памяти.